# facing the error after reading the change stream data from gcp cloud spanner and using the pcollection to query data from another spanner table

Tags: java, jdbc, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

`INFO: Autocommit has been disabled`
`[WARNING]` 
`org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcSqlExceptionFactory$JdbcSqlExceptionImpl: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Cannot set autocommit while a transaction is active`

below is the code how I read the change stream data from spanner

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<DataChangeRecord> inputChangeStreams = p.apply(SpannerIO
        .readChangeStream()
        .withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig)
        .withChangeStreamName(options.getChangeStreamTable())
        .withMetadataInstance(options.getInputInstanceId())
        .withMetadataDatabase(options.getInputDatabaseId())
        .withInclusiveStartAt(Timestamp.now()));

PCollection<KV<String, String>> enrichedDataStream = buildData(options, inputChangeStreams);
```

the buildData is as listed below where we get id column from change stream( where we apply windowing) and passing that in the query as parameter to get data from another table in spanner

```
private static PCollection<KV<String, String>> buildData(SpannerToSpannerPipelineOption options, PCollection<DataChangeRecord> inputChangeStreams) {

    PCollection<KV<String, String>> eData = null;
    
        PCollection<KV<String, Long>> changeStreamedData = inputChangeStreams
                //              .apply(ParDo.of(new CSDataTransformationFn(options)))
                .apply("Apply to get Id from CS", ParDo.of(new DoFn<DataChangeRecord, Long>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {

                        c.element().getMods().forEach(mod -> {
                                    JSONObject keysJson = new JSONObject(mod.getKeysJson());
                                    LOG.info("cs keyJson is:" + keysJson);

                                    
                                    long Id = keysJson.getLong(CONSTANTS.ID);
                                    c.output(Id);

                                }
                        );
                    }
                }))
                .apply("Apply Random Key", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Long, KV<String, Long>>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                        c.output(KV.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), c.element()));
                    }
                })).apply("Apply Fixed Length Windows", Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1))));


        changeStreamedData
                .apply("Print log", MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(String.class)).via(x -> {
                            LOG.info("incoming data is: " + x.getKey() + "value is" + x.getValue());
                            return x.getKey();
                        }
                ));


         eData = changeStreamedData
                .apply("Take each Id and lookup in the Input table", JdbcIO.<KV<String, Long>, KV<String, String>>readAll()
                        .withDataSourceConfiguration(
                                JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                                        CONSTANTS.SPANNERDRIVER,
                                        "jdbc:cloudspanner:/projects/" + options.getInputProjectId() + "/instances/" + options.getInputInstanceId() + "/databases/" + options.getInputDatabaseId()
                                )
                        )
                        .withQuery(CONSTANTS.QUERY)
                        .withParameterSetter((JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<KV<String, Long>>) (element, preparedStatement) -> {
                            preparedStatement.setLong(1, element.getValue());
                            LOG.info("element value is: " + element.getValue());
                        })
                        .withRowMapper((JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<String, String>>) resultSet -> {
                            String key = resultSet.getString(CONSTANTS.ID);

                            LOG.info("key value is: " + key);

                            ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();

                            // Iterate through each column to output
                            Map<String, Object> row = IntStream
                                    // Iterate through each column to output
                                    .range(1, resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1)
                                    // Output a pair with the column name and value.
                                    .mapToObj(i -> {
                                        
                                        try {
                                            LOG.info("Metadata2:" + KV.of(metadata.getColumnName(i), (resultSet != null && resultSet.getObject(i) != null) ? resultSet.getObject(i) : ""));
                                            return KV.of(metadata.getColumnName(i), ((resultSet != null && resultSet.getObject(i) != null) ? resultSet.getObject(i) : ""));
                                        } catch (SQLException ignored) {
                                            ignored.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    })

                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(KV::getKey, stringObjectKV1 -> stringObjectKV1 != null ? stringObjectKV1.getValue() : ""));
```

I am facing an intermittent issue with error saying

```
INFO: Autocommit has been disabled[WARNING] org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcSqlExceptionFactory$JdbcSqlExceptionImpl: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Cannot set autocommit while a transaction is active
```

and the spanner config automatically closes. I read from spanner and dataflow document that by default the autocommit is set to true, not sure why this is happening . Any help would be great

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do and where you're getting the error? Is it possible to share the documents you follow?

Comment: @kiranmathew yes sure..what I am trying to do is I have a change stream configured in gcp spanner which is basically an unbounded data and I am doing the windowing and getting the id column as mod.getKeysJson() and I need to pass this id to another spanner table which is bounded and execute the query which accepts this id as a parameter. But I believe while it is calling JdbcIO.<KV<String, Long>, KV<String, String>>readAll()  method, the autocommit is getting disabled and hence getting the error.The document I am referring are https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dataflow-connector

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.